# Apply homography on contours as well as Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

Currently I am using the following sequence

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours
1. findContours(srcMat, contours, ...)
2. convert contours to Point2f
3. findHomography(src, dst, RANSAC)
4. warpPerspective(srcMat, destMat, homo)
5. findContours
```

I would like to avoid step#4, while also transforming the Mat since I use some ROI relative to the contours from the transformed Mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to running warpPerspective but on contours is to use cv::perspectiveTransform with the translation matrix.
The limitation is that it can transform only one contour at a time. Sample below.

```
vector<vector<Point2f>> contours; // from findContours
Mat trnsmat = getPerspectiveTransform(srcPoints, destPoints);
for (int i=0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    cv::perspectiveTransform(contours[i], contours[i], trnsmat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your goal is to project the contour co-ordinates into the transformed space without using the entire image?

Load the contour co-ordinates into RoiMat structure and multiply it with the homography matrix computed using your findHomography function. 
There's no need to warp the entire original image for the same.

If you want to view the transformed ROI on the image, probably pick a few interest points(for reference) from the original image and add it to the RoiMat structure.

Comment: Thanks. I don't actually know the interest points till much later in the program, so the only way out warp the entire image (or largest ROI).

Two questions:
1. Would the contour background (say a hollow ring or square) be transformed as well? My guess is not.
2. Would performing vector<contours> multiplication with homoMat followed by warpPerspective be more efficient 
than 
warpPerspective followed by findContours.

Comment: I am trying to do the following and it is failing. What could be going wrong?

    Mat tmp(contour[0], false);
    tmp = tmp * homoMat;
    
The above leads to assertion failure.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can isolate each contour with the code below and afterwards do whatever processing you've to perform on each contour.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    contor_img = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Now you can process each contour individually(contor_img)

Comment: I have already outlined the steps including findContours in my questions. My query was how to just transform the contours without needing to transform the image and running findContours again.
Anyway I have solved it.